# Why does `long long typedef ll` work the same as `typedef long long ll`?

Tags: c++, typedef

Basically the title; I have stumbled across a C++ code which had `long long typedef LL;` instead of, what everyone would expect, something like `typedef long long LL;`. It magically worked!

I have never seen any documentation regarding this, nor I have any idea why would that work; does anybody have an idea?

Comment: And yet, it is documented on cppreference that [quote] *Typically, the typedef specifier appears at the start of the declaration, though it is permitted to appear after the type specifiers, or between two type specifiers.* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef

Comment: It's a weird quirk of the language that is used only if you want to confuse people, like writing `3[a]` instead of `a[3]`

Comment: It was g++ 10.2.0, but yes, I have seen the answers already. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `long typedef long LL;` :P

Comment: Who knew? I'm always learning from this site.

Comment: The only documentation you need (and the only one you can trust) is the language standard. (For us mere mortals a freely available final draft is fine). Just find `typedef` in the index and look at the corresponding section(s). [It's all there in plain sight](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef).

Comment: Or since we're talking about C++, you could just `using LL = long long;`

Comment: @Chris That would be my reaction too ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- my reaction would be to not do it at all. <g>

Comment: Do be careful with this. In any long, non-toy program the time saved typing `LL` instead of `long long` is eaten up by having to de-obfuscate the code when debugging. Keep the code expressive, it's meaning obvious to human readers, and you'll find mistakes often make themselves similarly obvious to human readers. Often your legacy after leaving a company is not in the code you wrote, but in how few violent curses people say when reading your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fair enough, C++ really  is missing a strongly typed alias :(

Comment: _Or_ just include `<cstdint>` and use `int64_t`.